# About the three point function at one loop order

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, trace

Could someone explain how exactly do you calculate the trace of the three point function of one loop in QED. in the following link the expression from 1. a (2)

http://learn.tsinghua.edu.cn:8080/2010310800/Webpage/files/Peskin_Schroeder/Peskin_Chap10.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source you linked to looks for the divergent part of the integral in a high energy limit ($m \to 0$). If you want to compute the whole thing, here's how you would do it. Focus on just one of the two traces:

1) "Rationalize" all the propagators by doing something like

$$
\frac{1}{\gamma^\mu k_\mu - m} = \frac{\gamma^\mu k_\mu + m}{k^2 - m^2}
$$

1)[Result] Now the numerator is something like

$$ \prod_i \left\{ \left( \gamma^{\mu_i} p_{i,\mu_i} + m_i \right) \text{ or } \gamma^{\mu_i} \right\} $$

i.e. a product of terms that are either a gamma matrix or consist of some slashed momentum with a possible mass term.

2) Expand this product term by term. For example, pick $m$ every time, or pick the slashed momentum every time.

2)[Result] Now the matrix part looks like

$$
\sum_{terms} m^n p_{1,\mu_1} \cdots p_{j,\mu_j} tr \left[ \gamma^{\mu_1} \cdots \gamma^{\mu_i} \cdots \gamma^{\mu_j} \right]
$$

Some subset of the gamma matrices in the trace are contracted with the momenta four-vectors, but there are a number of un-contracted gamma matrices. In fact, for this example there should be three.

3) For each term, use the following trace identities to simplify (there are others, but there are the most relevant ones):

- trace of an odd number of gamma matrices is 0
- $ tr \left[ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \right] = 4 g^{\mu \nu} $
- $ tr \left[ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho \gamma^\sigma \right] = 4 \left( g^{\mu \nu} g^{\rho \sigma} - g^{\mu \rho} g^{\nu \sigma} + g^{\mu \sigma} g^{\nu \rho} \right)$
- the cyclic property: $ tr \left[ \gamma^\mu \cdots \gamma^\nu \right] = tr \left[ \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu \cdots \right] $

You might frequently need to use other gamma matrix identities such as:

$$ \left\{ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \right\} = 2 g^{\mu \nu} $$

You'll need this when figuring out the trace of a product of 6, 8, etc. gamma matrices, in which case you can use the anticommutation relation to move a gamma matrix all the way across, hop it back with the cyclic property, and then rearrange terms to write the formula for the trace of N gamma matrices in terms of traces of N-2 gamma matrices. This is how you'd prove the identity for the trace of 4 gamma matrices, for example.

3) [Result] Now the expression is a sum of terms involving Lorentz contractions of the various momenta involved.

I don't mean these steps to be the exact order you should compute things in. Doing things in exactly this order is definitely not the most efficient way to proceed. But, this is the overall scheme.

Comment: could it be possible to just set all the masses and external momenta equal to zero?

Comment: This is what was done in problem 1b) the link you provided, because the author there was not trying to evaluate that integral completely. Rather, the author was interested in the possibility of a divergent part of the integral, i.e. a UV part that blows up over the large k part of the integral. The external momenta and mass are irrelevant for this part of the integral, where $p, m \ll k$. Since the author was only checking to see if there was a divergent part, simplifying the expression by putting the external momenta and mass to 0 is a good idea.